# why value is not being inserted into table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, database, laravel

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#first_form").submit(feedtable);
    function feedtable(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var task = $("#fname").val(),
  male = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val(),
  //female = $("#female:checked").val(),
  desc = $("#age").val(),
  type = $("#city").val();      
  console.log(male);
  console.log(task);
  console.log(type);     
  $('#content').append(
    "<tr><td>"+task+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+male+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+desc+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+type+"</td>"+
    "<td>"+"uyt"+"</td></tr>"
  );   
}
```

});

I am using #first_form named form and want to insert values in #content named table
Every output is showing in console but values are not inserting in table
HTML code is bit of messy
here i want to insert values from form to the table
it is not giving any error every value i enter in form i displayed in console but value is not adding in table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./one.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{background-color:  rgb(175, 166, 166);}
        #tablee{border: 2px solid rgb(13, 13, 14);
            margin-top: 0px;
            width:fit-content;}
         .content{border-collapse: collapse;
          margin: 5px 0;
          font-size: 0.9em;
          min-width: 400px;
          border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);}
        #inp {margin-left: 500px;
              border: 2px solid rgb(13, 13, 14);
              width:fit-content;height:fit-content;
        }
       #inp form{overflow: hidden;}
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tablee">
        <table class="content">
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Gender</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Action</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>ahmad</td>
                  <td>hgg</td>
                  <td>34</td>
                  <td>fdf</td>
                  <td>rrgr</td>
              </tr>           
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id="inp">
        <form id=first_form>
            <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="NAME"><br><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="gender" class="male" value="male">
            <label for="Male">Male</label><br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="gender" class="male" value="female">
            <label for="female">Female</label><br><br>
            <label for="age">Age:</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Age" value="0" max="999" min="1"><br><br>
            <label for="city">Choose a city:</label>
            <select name="city" id="city" placeholder="Select CIty"> 
            <option value="lahore">lahore</option>
            <option value="karachi">karachi</option>
            <option value="multan">Multan</option>
            <option value="islamabad">Islamabad</option>         
        </select>
        <br>     
            <input type="submit" onclick="" value="submit" button class="button">           
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: Welcome Atta to SO, Could you please share your AJAX request code as well.

Comment: i want to just insert data localy so no ajax is involved

Comment: You are using classname "content" for table element  but in the selector you are using id selector. Either change **$("#content")** to **$(".content")** or ... ```<table class="content"> to <table id="content">```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch. Replace the variable name "type" with something else. As you can see, it is rendered as keyword. Might mean something.